# Should formatter do validation?

Tags: user-interface, websites, validation

Say I have a SSN field in a form. I want SSN to be in format of `xxx-xx-xxx`.

I may just have a SSN formatter checking whether the input are all digits and adding dashes when necessary.

Another option is to have both SSN formatter and validator. SSN formatter doesn't check type or range, so it accepts `asdfghjkl` and formats to `asd-fg-hjkl`. Then regular expression validator kicks in, telling me the input doesn't matach pattern `\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{3}`.

I find some formatting libraries have built-in validation functions, eg. [formatter.js](https://github.com/firstopinion/formatter.js) and [FieldKit](http://square.github.io/field-kit/).

If formatter does both formatting and validating, is it single responsibility?

Comment: SRP doesn't mean what you think it means.

Comment: @RobertHarvey  So what does SRP mean? Too long to explain here, right?

Answer (score 2):

The Single Responsibility Principle applies to classes of objects.

Robert Martin defines a "responsibility" as "a reason for the class to change," which basically means that a class can do more than one thing, so long as those things are related.  For example, a data access class might have Create, Read, Update and Delete methods, but that doesn't mean it has four responsibilities, only one: that of data access.

Ergo, it's entirely reasonable for formatting and validation to be in one class, as both activities relate to the responsibility of managing UI input.

SRP goes hand-in-hand with the Open/Closed principle, which states that a class should be "open for extension, but closed for modification."  Classes which adhere to SRP are easier to extend, because you're not dealing with multiple responsibilities but only a single one.

**Further Reading**
[Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)
[Open/Closed Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle)

Comment: Ok, makes sense. Is it really a good idea to format while validating? I think  separating into two steps is clearer and easier to implement and maintain .

Comment: Then do it that way.